# Spring jms separator by messageId

Tags: java, spring, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am using `@JmsListener` annotation to receive all message from queue

```
@JmsListener(destination = MyQueue, selector = "MAINST = '" + instanceName + "'")
            public void receivMsg(Message message) {
```

But another system doesn't work with message properties. It responds with correlation id. How I can filter messages by correlationIDs, when there are in `LinkedList<String>`

Answer (score 2):

Use a property placeholder for `instanceName`. Here's an example with two listeners on the same queue...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So48377178Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So48377178Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(JmsTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            template.convertAndSend("foo", "This one's for A", m -> {
                m.setJMSCorrelationID("A");
                return m;
            });
            template.convertAndSend("foo", "This one's for B", m -> {
                m.setJMSCorrelationID("B");
                return m;
            });
        };
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "foo", selector = "JMSCorrelationID='${a.instance}'")
    public void listenA(Message message) {
        System.out.println("A: " + message);
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "foo", selector = "JMSCorrelationID='${b.instance}'")
    public void listenB(Message message) {
        System.out.println("B: " + message);
    }

}
```

with

```
a.instance=A
b.instance=B
```

and

```
B: ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:gollum.local-56240-1516631774140-4:4:1:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:gollum.local-56240-1516631774140-4:4:1:1, destination = queue://foo, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1516631774348, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1516631774348, brokerOutTime = 1516631774349, correlationId = B, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = null, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 1056, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = This one's for B}
A: ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:gollum.local-56240-1516631774140-4:3:1:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:gollum.local-56240-1516631774140-4:3:1:1, destination = queue://foo, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1516631774341, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1516631774341, brokerOutTime = 1516631774345, correlationId = A, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = null, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 1056, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = This one's for A}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select by JMS Correlation ID by using that header property's name:

```
selector = "JMSCorrelationID = '" + something + "'"
```

Also checkout the **Message Selector** section of the Message API: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html

Comment: it doesn't work. Because "something" must be string constant

Comment: Ah, ok, yes. The subscriber and the correlation ID is a rather heavy-weight object. There's no need to create one for each message (or correlation ID). Couldn't you just throw them out if not needed ? Something like: if( !msg.getJMSCorrelationID().equals(something) ) return;

Comment: Because another app also listens to this queue.

Comment: how about using a topic?